# Find string with max number of tokens using Apache Beam's Python SDK

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a PCollection containing strings. I want to split each string by space and find the token list with **maximum size** and store the size in a variable as an `int`.

Consider this example input:

```py
sentences = ['This is the first sentence',
             'Second sentence',
             'Yet another sentence']

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
       pcoll = p | 'Create' >> beam.Create(sentences)
```

The sentences after splitting would be:

```
['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence'] -> 5
['Second', 'sentence'] -> 2
['Yet', 'another', 'sentence'] -> 3
```

I want to store the value `5` in a variable.

How do I go about doing this? I came across [this blogpost](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2017/09/12/apache-beam-quick-start-with-python/), but it doesn't completely serve my purpose. The author is printing out the resultant PCollection, but I want to use this value later in other stages of the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with the [`Top.of`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.transforms.combiners.html?highlight=top#apache_beam.transforms.combiners.Top) transform. Briefly, we split each sentence and then calculate the token length. With `Top` we just want the number one result and we pass a lambda function as the comparison criteria to sort them by word length:

```
sentences = sentences = ['This is the first sentence',
       'Second sentence',
       'Yet another sentence']

longest_sentence = (p
  | 'Read Sentences' >> beam.Create(sentences)
  | 'Split into Words' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
  | 'Map Token Length'      >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, len(x)))
  | 'Top Sentence' >> combine.Top.Of(1, lambda a,b: a[1]<b[1])
  | 'Save Variable'         >> beam.ParDo(SaveMaxFn()))
```

where `SaveMaxFn()`is:

```
class SaveMaxFn(beam.DoFn):
  """Stores max in global variables"""
  def process(self, element):
    length = element[0][1]
    logging.info("Longest sentence: %s tokens", length)

    return element
```

and `length` is a global variable:

```
global length
```

Result:

```
INFO:root:Longest sentence: 5 token(s)
```

Full code:

```
import argparse, logging

import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.transforms.combiners as combine
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


class SaveMaxFn(beam.DoFn):
  """Stores max in global variables"""
  def process(self, element):
    length = element[0][1]
    logging.info("Longest sentence: %s token(s)", length)

    return element


def run(argv=None):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  global length

  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

  sentences = sentences = ['This is the first sentence',
             'Second sentence',
             'Yet another sentence']

  longest_sentence = (p
    | 'Read Sentences' >> beam.Create(sentences)
    | 'Split into Words' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
    | 'Map Token Length'      >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, len(x)))
    | 'Top Sentence' >> combine.Top.Of(1, lambda a,b: a[1]<b[1])
    | 'Save Variable'         >> beam.ParDo(SaveMaxFn()))

  result = p.run()
  result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

Comment: @xennygrimmato could you please help me understand what does 'b' argument in lambda function takes? What are we passing for 'b' ?